# How to validate params in GET, POST request?

Tags: python, api, validation, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have view and serialiser. How i can validate params in GET `api/transaction?date=2019-11-05` and POST requests.
**view***

```
class TransactionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Transaction.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TransactionSerializer
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
```

**serialiser**

```
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    transfers = TransferSerializer(many=True)
    partner_transaction = PartnerTransactionDataSerializer(many=True)
    purchase_transaction = PurchaseTransactionDataSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = (
            'created_at',
            'transaction_type_id',
            'transfers',
            'partner_transaction',
            'purchase_transaction'
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

you can override queryset method in views

```
class TransactionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Transaction.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TransactionSerializer
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        date = self.request.GET.get('date')
        return super().get_queryset().filter(created_at=date)
```

Comment: but ```LimitOffsetPagination``` doesn work